# Keep state/session between tests in capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

So I am writing some integration tests using rails 4.0 + rspec + capybara + databasecleaner.

Currently, every test is a completely isolated thing. Meaning, if I want to write a "story" that tests changing some user settings, I need to first login, then navigate to the user settings and change for example the user's name, for one test. Then I'd have to do the entire process again to test the changing of the user's email.

How could I write a story where every test starts on the same page, without using a `before :each`?

I'm unable to find any documentation, so any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For an integration test, it seems that you should be able to use the `sign_in` test helper (for Devise) or mimic a "signed in" user via the third parameter to `post` or `put`:


    post 'edit', {hash of parameters to update here}, {user_id: user.id}

The `before(:each)` then sets up the necessary model data to allow for the `post` action to take effect, and a `sign_in` helper if you can't pass in a session via the post itself.

Comment: @stringsn88keys that would just be 1 step: the logging in of the user. It would rather be to avoid the creating of the user + navigating to a certain page all the time. It's slow when that has to happen all the time, while consecutive tests need to be on that same exact page.